# how to get differnce between two gps address

Tags: android, gps

I have two longitude and latitude values. i.e.,

**longitude1** and **latitude1** are came from webservice

and **longitude2** and **latitude2** are my device values.

So i want to calculate the difference between these two address. So i tried below code

```
private Geocoder geocoder;

geocoder=new Geocoder(this);

Address address1=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude1,longitude1,1).get(0);

Address address2=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude2,longitude2,1).get(0);
```

So i want to know difference between address1,address2. So please tell me how to find the difference between **address1**, **address2**.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: what do you mean by "difference"? you mean distance ? if longitude + latitude are equals ?

Comment: no address1 is came from webservice and address2 is my device address. So i want to calculate difference between these two address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method 
`Location.distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results);`

so the result[0] has the approximate distance in meters between two locations.

Comment: When iuse this method it gives me illegal argument exception it says results might null or less than < 1 What should i do ? \

Comment: @raghavchopra are you passing null in last argument for results float[]. it must be float[] of length 2

Comment: Array of Float[] will give us results right ? If No What should i pass in the array of float

Comment: yes, float[] array of size 2, it can be of size 1. See the API documentation

Answer (score 1):

[Actually, you'll have to use the following to properly calculate the value.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

Comment: This gives a good "as the crow flies" difference, its one I use on some apps I have for filtering "get addresses less than x miles away" queries...I still get complaints as it doesn't match the DRIVING distance exactly.

Comment: Indeed, as the formula is based on a perfect sphere whereas our little ball of rock in the solor system isn't that perfect in most locations.  Oh well, still does a pretty good job, though.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the latitudes and longitudes captured (`latitude1, longitude1`) simply subtract the 1 and 2 and take the `Math.abs()` value as your distancex, distancey.  then apply pythagoras to find the actual distance.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: I'm pretty sure your suggestion will yield an incorrect value as "you will be traveling through the Earth".

Comment: Have to remember that the Earth is curved. Great Circle is the way forward.